# vector<tuple<A,B> > to map<A,B>

Tags: c++, vectors, container

i have an `vector<tuple<A,b> > v` and want to make a `map<A,B>` from it
i came up with 3 variants:

```
std::transform(v.begin(),v.end(), std::inserter(map,map.begin()),[](std::tuple<int,char> t){
    return std::make_pair(std::get<0>(t),std::get<1>(t));
});
```

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](std::tuple<int,char> t){
    map.insert(std::make_pair(std::get<0>(t),std::get<1>(t)));
});
```

```
for (auto t : v) {
    map.insert(std::make_pair(std::get<0>(t),std::get<1>(t)));
}
```

is `shorter is better` the way to go here? could one simplify the `tuple`=>`pair` conversion? thanks

Answer (score 4):

I would use the last as the simplest, yes.  I'd probably write a `pair_from_tuple` helper function to not have to write out the `std::get` explicitly.

The first and second both require you to write out the tuple type.  This will change soon, but not everyone will immediately have C++14.  Also, they're easier to get wrong; I think you mean to specify capture-by-reference in example 2, for example.

With `pair_from_tuple`, I suppose

```
using std::begin;
using std::end;
std::transform(begin(v), end(v), std::inserter{map, map.begin()}, pair_from_tuple<int, char>);
```

would be okay (you can avoid the `<int, char>` by making `pair_from_tuple` a functor).  Still less nice than

```
for (auto const& e : v)
    map.insert(pair_from_tuple(e));
```

, though.

Comment: Cool: Never seen pair_from_tuple before. :-)

Comment: @Loki: I'm suggesting he write it. :)